# Problems with tensorflow_hub and tensorflow 1.10

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am using tensorflow hub 0.11 with tensorflow 1.10 while I have errors like this:

```
tensorflow hub depends on 'tf-nightly' build after 20180308 or 'tensorflow~=1.7'. found tf.version = 1.10.0
```

I run the code below but it does not help:

```
pip install --user tensorflow --upgrade
pip install --user tensorflow_hub --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got comes from tensorflow_hub 0.1.0. Please check your set-up and how pip changed it to actually use tensorflow_hub 0.1.1, which has this version check removed.

Comment: I finally manually removed it from \_\_init\_\_.py of tensorflow hub